# How to conditionally style specific characters inside a <span> in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(New to React) I have a dynamic form where the user can write a text in the input and by clicking submit, the input bar will disappear and a  with the text that was written will show up on screen.
If the user types an underscore ('_'), that character should be styled with a different color from the rest of the string. I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Thus far I have this:

```
<form onSubmit={submit}>
                    
                    {formFields.map((form, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className='tfRow'>
                                <div className='tfClmnL'>
                                    {!isShown && 
                                        <input
                                            name='question'
                                            className='questionInput'
                                            placeholder='Question'
                                            onChange={event => handleFormChange(event, index)}
                                            value={form.question}
                                            style={{marginLeft: '30px', width: '450px'}}
                                        />
                                    }
                                    {isShown && <span className='questionSpan' style={{ color: form.question.includes('_') ?  '#E11F6E' : 'black'}}>
                                        <span style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{index+1})</span> {form.question}
                                    </span>}

                                </div>
                            
                                {!isShown && <button style={{marginRight: '0px'}}className='commandWhite cancel' alt='alternative' title='Remove Question' onClick={() => removeFields(index)}><img className='blackIcon' src={blackCancel}/></button>}
                                
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </form>
```

But this way, if an underscore is found, the entire string will be turned to a different color. How can I achieve the effect only for the desired character?

Comment: Maybe try wrapping the character in another <span class="underscore_char"> once found, and removing if deleted

Answer (score 1):

in `handleFormChange`, you can change the value text.

```js
const highlightedValue = inputValue.replace(
  new RegExp(stringToHighlight, "gi"),
  `<span class='highlight'>${stringToHighlight}</span>`
);

inputField.value = highlightedValue;
```